# How to store a multiple choice useful in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

this is all about how to store content in the most efficient way in a database.
The most important thing here is not to save as much space as possible - the focus lays on the fastest way to use this data.

So in general its an easy thing :

We have 10 choices with radio boxes - we can select ALL or we can select none - or just select one/some of 'em.

So in general I see two general options to save the result in my database :

A) Just make 10 Fields on my table with Tinyint(1) and set a 0 or 1

B) I could use ONE Int(7) which will have the chance to decode the result like a binary system - f.E. if you choose option 3, 5 & 8 its like 00101001.

So the question is which makes more sense ?

B will take only 4 Bytes and A will take 8 Bytes - besides B will need a short PHP function to decode the binary thing.

The question now what option do you think will be of better usage sooner or later if the database get a hell of querys ?

Comment: What about an enum with all possible options?

Comment: That's 2^10 options, or 1024 options...

Comment: with 1 billion records sql query take only 1sec. what do you think ? why would you save your data like the day of new generation x86 pc with floppy disk 1.4MB ?

Comment: exactly - so I never thought ENUM will be a real use here :/

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to have 10 different fields, unless you know that each query will always need ALL 10 fields.

It'll be easier for the programmer (not always having to calculate bitvectors). It's easier to add new columns or remove them. You can put small, fast indexes on some columns, but not all.

Comment: I know I will ALWAYS need all 10 of em.